# Error when trying to add dataframes together: Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am creating dataframes in a loop. At the end of each loop, I would like to add all data frames together. Its a pretty long and complicated code for the loop, but what I did is created an empty list called "datalist" before the loop and then added the dataframes to the loop. that worked fine. After the loop, I wrote:

```
big_data = do.call("rbind",datalist)
```

this hits me with the error

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ‘4’
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Before `rbind`ing your data.frames, consider "flushing" rownames with `rownames(x) <- NULL`.

Comment: Roman, unfortunately that didnt work- I tried doing that in the loop before adding the data frame to the list, and also after th eloop before calling rbind on the list. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I had the same problem; the issue turned out to be that I unintentionally had put a data.frame nested inside my data.frame. Found the problem (and resolved it) thanks to the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115910/8436923